# Why $nin is slower than $in, Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have collection with 5M documents with correct indexes.$in working perfect, but same query with $nin super slow...What of the reason of this?

Super fast:

```
{'tech': {'$in': ['Wordpress', 'wordpress', 'WORDPRESS']}}
```

Super slow..

```
{'tech': {'$nin': ['Wordpress', 'wordpress', 'WORDPRESS']}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

### The following explanation is accurate only for Mongo versions prior to 3.2

Mongo v3.2 has all kinds of storage engine changes which improved performance on this issue.

Now `$nin` hash one important quality, which is it not a [selective](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/core/query-optimization/#query-optimization) query, First let's understand what [selectivity](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/core/query-optimization/#query-optimization) means:

> Selectivity is the ability of a query to narrow results using the index. Effective indexes are more selective and allow MongoDB to use the index for a larger portion of the work associated with fulfilling the query.

Now they even state it themselfs:

> For instance, the inequality operators $nin and $ne are not very selective since they often match a large portion of the index. As a result, in many cases, a $nin or $ne query with an index may perform no better than a $nin or $ne query that must scan all documents in a collection.

Back then `selectivity` was a big deal performance wise. This all leads us to your question, why isn't the index being used?

Well when Mongo is asked to create a query plan he preforms a "race" between all available query plans, one of which is a `COLSCAN` i.e collection scan where the first plan to find 101 documents wins. Due to the poor efficiency of non-selective query's the winning plan (And actually usually faster depending on the index and values in the query) is `COLSCAN`, Read further about this [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/core/query-plans/#query-optimization)

Comment: What is the way to do $nin with same speed as $in? Maybe some tricks?

Comment: In Mongo versions prior to 3.2 that will never happen, in more current version i'd say it heavily relies on the values you exclude and the structure of the index tree. still you can't compare the two in terms of performance.

Answer (score 3):

When you have an index (no matter if you talk about MongoDB or any other database), it is always faster to search for a certain value, than searching for a non-existing value.

The database has to scan the entire index, often the index is even not used when you look for "not in" or "not equal". Have a look at execution plan with `explain()`

Some databases (e.g. Oracle) provide so called Bitmap Indexes. They work differently and usually an `IN` operation is as fast as an `NOT IN` operation. But, as usual they have other drawbacks compared to B*Tree Indexes. According to my knowledge Oracle Database is the only major RDBMS which supports Bitmap Indexes.