# is there any workarround on $nin slowness on mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm implementing a pipeline on mongo which have this structure:

```js
db.COLLECTION.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {
                    "code": { $nin: ArrayOfValidCodes },
                    "Type": { $in: ["T1", "T2"] },
                    "date": { $lte: myDate }  
                },
                {
                    "code": { $nin: ArrayOfValidCodesForT3 },
                    "Type": { $in: ["T3"] },
                    "date": { $lte: myDate }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    { 
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            code: 1,
        },
    },
    {
        "$sort": { _id : -1 }
    },
    {
        "$limit": 100
    }
])
```

As I read from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122731/why-nin-is-slower-than-in-mongodb) $nin is considerably slower than an $in but is there any workarround?

This `code` property sometimes is modified incorrectly by people so I want to get those invalid codes to fix them.

Answer (score -1):

I would try to add index to "code property" and then filter by utilizing $regexMatch.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/

Comment: Consider adopting the code sample provided by OP and creating a code segment on how to apply the $regexMatch on OP's scenario with explanation.

Comment: @ray how can I provide code explanation when OP did not provide any valid or invalid values ? You were so quick to downwote the answer that you forgot how regex works ?

Comment: Consider commenting on the question to ask for clarification and MRE then. Your answer seems a "link-only answer", which is often considered low-quality in SO.

Comment: yup, but the OP didn't provide much context in terms of values that he wants filtered. I could do nothing more.
I think it was better like this, than to leave question unanswered, right ?  and when he sees this, hopefully he will provide some context.